# Is Apache Xerces a Streaming XML parser?

Tags: java, xerces, castor

I am writing an application that needs to unmarshall a huge XML file using [castor](http://castor.codehaus.org/). Because of this reason, I need use a streaming XML parser such as Stax to parse the XML file. 
According to Castor's documentation, castor default parser is Xerces. I visited Xerces home page, and I could not find any information whether Xerces is a streaming parser or not.

Does anyone know whether Xerces is a streaming parser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerces:

> Xerces is Apache's collection of software libraries for parsing,
>   validating, serializing and manipulating XML. The library implements a
>   number of standard APIs for XML parsing, including DOM, SAX and SAX2

So it seems to support streaming and non streaming APIs. See http://xerces.apache.org/#xerces2-j for all supported APIs.

Answer (score 2):

There is some advice [on the FAQ](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/faq-write.html#faq-11) on how to handle this situation. Quoting the docs.

> **How do I read data from a stream as it arrives?**
>
> There are 3 problems you have to deal with:

- The Apache parsers read the entire data stream into a buffer before
  they start parsing; you need to change this behaviour, so that they
  analyse "on the fly"
- The Apache parsers terminate when they reach end-of-file; with a data
  stream, unless the sender drops the socket, you have no end-of-file,
  so you need to terminate in some other way
- The Apache parsers close the input stream on termination, and this
  closes the socket; you normally don't want this, because you'll want
  to send an ack to the data stream source, and you may want to have
  further exchanges on the socket anyway.